# Importing a python script/module that uses argparse into another python script

Tags: python, import, argparse

This question may be regarded to be redundant but, to my defense, I've considered similar questions and given solutions but they don't work for me (or I just didn't understand them) as I will show.

**What I want to do:**
I wrote a couple of python scripts that are each command-line tools (accepting several arguments using argparse) when built with pyinstaller. They all work as expected both from within pycharm's terminal and from the Ubuntu terminal. Now, I would like each of these scripts to be a module that could be called from another python script passing required arguments as I would do in the terminal.

**This is one of the original scripts** (I've shortened the script a bit so that it serves as a minimal example):

```
import sys
import argparse
import getpass


if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "You haven't specified any arguments. Use -h to get more details on how to use this command."
    sys.exit(1)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--username', '-u', type=str, default=None, help='Username for the login to the WebCTRL server')
parser.add_argument('--password', '-p', type=str, default=None, help='Password for the login to the WebCTRL server')
parser.add_argument('--node', '-n', type=str, default=None,
    help='Path to the point or node whose children you want to retrieve. Start querying at the lowest level with "-n /trees/geographic"')
parser.add_argument('-url', type=str, default='https://my.server.de',
    help="URL of the WebCTRL server as e.g. http://google.de")
args = parser.parse_args()


if args.username is None:
    print 'No user name specified. Login to WebCTRL needs a user name and password. Check all options for this command via -h'
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    username = args.username
if args.password is None:
    password = getpass.getpass('No password specified via -p. Please enter your WebCTRL login password: ')
else:
    password = args.password
if args.node is None:
    print 'No path to a node specified. Check all options for this command via -h'
    sys.exit(1)
if args.url is None:
    print 'No URL given. Specify the URL to the WebCTRL server analogous to http://google.de'
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    wsdlFile = args.url + '/_common/webservices/Eval?wsdl'


# This doesn't belong to my original code. It's rather for demonstration:
# Print the arguments and leave the script
print 'Username: ' + args.username
print 'Node: ' + args.node
print 'URL: ' + args.url

sys.exit(0)
```

As I said: From within my IDE (Pycharm) ...

```
$ python wc_query_test.py -u wsdl -n /trees/geographic
No password specified via -p. Please enter your WebCTRL login password: 
Username: wsdl
Node: /trees/geographic
URL: https://my.server.de
```

... and from the Ubuntu terminal it works just fine:

```
$ pyinstaller --distpath dist/. wc_query_test.py
$ ./dist/wc_query_test/wc_query_test -u wsdl -n /trees/geographic
No password specified via -p. Please enter your WebCTRL login password: 
Username: wsdl
Node: /trees/geographic
URL: https://my.server.de
```

**Coming to the actual problem:**
I want the script wc_query_test.py to be a module that can be imported into another python script and executed there passing along the arguments as I do in the command line. To achieve this I followed @Waylan's instructions in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440441/importing-a-python-script-from-another-script-and-running-it-with-arguments).

This is the code I came up with (wc_query_test.py):

```
import sys
import argparse
import getpass

def main(**kwargs):
    if kwargs.username is None:
        print 'No user name specified. Login to WebCTRL needs a user name and password. Check all options for this command via -h'
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        username = kwargs.username
    if kwargs.password is None:
        password = getpass.getpass('No password specified via -p. Please enter your WebCTRL login password: ')
    else:
        password = kwargs.password
    if kwargs.node is None:
        print 'No path to a node specified. Check all options for this command via -h'
        sys.exit(1)
    if kwargs.url is None:
        print 'No URL given. Specify the URL to the WebCTRL server analogous to http://google.de'
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        wsdlFile = kwargs.url + '/_common/webservices/Eval?wsdl'

    # This doesn't belong to my original code. It's rather for demonstration:
    # Print the arguments and leave the script
    print 'Username: ' + username
    print 'Node: ' + kwargs.node
    print 'URL: ' + kwargs.url

    sys.exit(0)

def run():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--username', '-u', type=str, default=None, help='Username for the login to the WebCTRL server')
    parser.add_argument('--password', '-p', type=str, default=None, help='Password for the login to the WebCTRL server')
    parser.add_argument('--node', '-n', type=str, default=None,
        help='Path to the point or node whose children you want to retrieve. Start querying at the lowest level with "-n /trees/geographic"')
    parser.add_argument('-url', type=str, default='https://my.server.de',
        help="URL of the WebCTRL server as e.g. http://google.de")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(**args)
```

... and the script that imports the module and calls it (test.py):

```
import wc_query_test
wc_query_test.main(username='wsdl', password='aaaaaa', node='/trees/geographic')
```

When I run it in the python terminal I get:

```
~/PycharmProjects/webctrl$ python wc_query_test.py
~/PycharmProjects/webctrl$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    wc_query_test.main(username='wsdl', password='aaaaaa', node='/trees/geographic/#geb_g', url='https://webctrl.rz-berlin.mpg.de')
  File "/home/stefan/PycharmProjects/webctrl/wc_query_test.py", line 23, in main
    if kwargs.username is None:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Running wc_query_test.py yields no output and I see why this is. That was just a test. But running test.py yields an error as well. I get an idea why this can't work either but I cannot put it into words. What about this run() method? Does it make sense to have it? How would I need to modify my code in order to obtain this dual functionality as described in "What I want to do:"? Thank you in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:**
I got rid of the error message. I changed e.g. `kwargs.username` to `kwargs.get('username')` since kwargs is a dictionary. The code now looks like this:

```
import sys
import argparse
import getpass

def main(**kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('username') is None:
        print 'No user name specified. Login to WebCTRL needs a user name and password. Check all options for this command via -h'
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        username = kwargs.get('username')
    if kwargs.get('password') is None:
        password = getpass.getpass('No password specified via -p. Please enter your WebCTRL login password: ')
    else:
        password = kwargs.get('password')
    if kwargs.get('node') is None:
        print 'No path to a node specified. Check all options for this command via -h'
        sys.exit(1)
    if kwargs.get('url') is None:
        print 'No URL given. Specify the URL to the WebCTRL server analogous to http://google.de'
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        wsdlFile = kwargs.get('url') + '/_common/webservices/Eval?wsdl'

    # This doesn't belong to my original code. It's rather for demonstration:
    # Print the arguments and leave the script
    print 'Username: ' + username
    print 'Node: ' + kwargs.get('node')
    print 'URL: ' + kwargs.get('url')

    sys.exit(0)

def run():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--username', '-u', type=str, default=None, help='Username for the login to the WebCTRL server')
    parser.add_argument('--password', '-p', type=str, default=None, help='Password for the login to the WebCTRL server')
    parser.add_argument('--node', '-n', type=str, default=None,
        help='Path to the point or node whose children you want to retrieve. Start querying at the lowest level with "-n /trees/geographic"')
    parser.add_argument('-url', type=str, default='https://webctrl.rz-berlin.mpg.de',
        help="URL of the WebCTRL server as e.g. http://google.de")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(**args)
```

Running it in the python terminal yields as expected:

```
$ python test.py 
Username: wsdl
Node: /trees/geographic
URL: https://my.server.de
```

But building it via pyinstaller and running it as command line tool there is no output:

```
~/PycharmProjects/webctrl$ ./dist/wc_query_test/wc_query_test -h
~/PycharmProjects/webctrl$
```

How can I modify wc_query_test.py so that it takes arguments and serves as command line tool?

Comment: `kwargs` is a dict, which has no attribute 'username', just like the error states. You want item access: `kwargs['username']`. Note that `main(**args)` will also fail, since the `Namespace` object from `parse_args()` is not a mapping. A quick and dirty solution is to `main(**vars(args))`.

Comment: Also your `main()` function should not print an erreor message and call `sys.exit()` but raise an exception (with the error message).

Comment: Without studying your code in detail, I noticed one glaring problem.  It is best to call the parser in a `if __name__` block.  That way it is used only when the script is called as a script, not when imported by another.  Running parsers in several imported scripts is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded. With the help of a colleague I got the answer to my question. This is the functioning code:

**wc_query_test.py**:

```
import sys
import argparse
import getpass

def main(args):
    if args['username'] is None:
        print 'No user name specified. Login to WebCTRL needs a user name and password. Check all options for this command via -h'
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        username = args['username']
    if args['password'] is None:
        password = getpass.getpass('No password specified via -p. Please enter your WebCTRL login password: ')
    else:
        password = args['password']
    if args['node'] is None:
        print 'No path to a node specified. Check all options for this command via -h'
        sys.exit(1)
    if args['url'] is None:
        print 'No URL given. Specify the URL to the WebCTRL server analogous to http://google.de'
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        wsdlFile = args['url'] + '/_common/webservices/Eval?wsdl'

    # This doesn't belong to my original code. It's rather for demonstration:
    # Print the arguments and leave the script
    print 'Username: ' + args['username']
    print 'Node: ' + args['node']
    print 'URL: ' + args['url']


# The parser is only called if this script is called as a script/executable (via command line) but not when imported by another script
if __name__=='__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print "You haven't specified any arguments. Use -h to get more details on how to use this command."
        sys.exit(1)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--username', '-u', type=str, default=None, help='Username for the login to the WebCTRL server')
    parser.add_argument('--password', '-p', type=str, default=None, help='Password for the login to the WebCTRL server')
    parser.add_argument('--node', '-n', type=str, default=None,
        help='Path to the point or node whose children you want to retrieve. Start querying at the lowest level with "-n /trees/geographic"')
    parser.add_argument('-url', type=str, default='https://webctrl.rz-berlin.mpg.de',
        help="URL of the WebCTRL server as e.g. http://google.de")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Convert the argparse.Namespace to a dictionary: vars(args)
    main(vars(args))
    sys.exit(0)
```

Now, there are three ways of executing wc_query_test which is what I wanted to achive:

1) Calling wc_query_test.py from command line:

```
~/PycharmProjects/webctrl$ python wc_query_test.py -u aawrg -p wgAWER -n YWERGAEWR
```

2) Compiling and calling wc_query_test from command line:

```
~/PycharmProjects/webctrl$ pyinstaller --distpath dist/. wc_query_test.py
~/PycharmProjects/webctrl$ ./dist/wc_query_test/wc_query_test -u aawrg -p wgAWER -n YWERGAEWR
```

3) Calling wc_query_test from another python script which goes into the direction of a module-type usage:

```
import wc_query_test
myDictonary = {'username':'wsdl', 'password':'aaaaaa', 'node':'/trees/geographic', 'url':'https://my.server.de'}
wc_query_test.main(myDictonary)
```

All three versions yield the same output as expected, for example:

```
~/PycharmProjects/webctrl$ ./dist/wc_query_test/wc_query_test -u aawrg -p wgAWER -n YWERGAEWR
Username: aawrg
Node: YWERGAEWR
URL: https://webctrl.rz-berlin.mpg.de
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Apparently I had to put the parser code inside the main function rather in the global scope of the imported script.

Answer (score 0):

The `**kwargs` is for passing a dictionary, or `keyword=value` pairs to a function.  `args = parser.parse_args()` returns an `argparse.Namespace` object, not a dictionary.  But `vars(args)` produces a dictionary from it.

```
In [2]: def foo1(args):
   ...:     print(args)
   ...:     print(args.foo)
   ...:     
In [3]: def foo2(**kwargs):
   ...:     print(kwargs)
   ...:     print(kwargs['foo'])

In [12]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [13]: p.add_argument('--foo');
In [14]: args = p.parse_args('--foo one'.split())
In [15]: args
Out[15]: Namespace(foo='one')
```

pass `args` to `foo1`:

```
In [16]: foo1(args)
Namespace(foo='one')
one
```

try it with `foo2`

```
In [17]: foo2(args)
...
TypeError: foo2() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

In [20]: foo2(**args)
TypeError: foo2() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Namespace
```

but pass the expanded dictionary version:

```
In [18]: vars(args)
Out[18]: {'foo': 'one'}
In [19]: foo2(**vars(args))
{'foo': 'one'}
one
```