# How to access arguments on an imported flask script which uses argparse?

Tags: python, flask, python-import, argparse, args

I have a python script say A which has some arguments specified using argparse in `main`.

```
.
.
def main(args):
  # use the arguments
.
.

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(..)
  parser.add_argument(
        '-c',
        '--classpath',
        type=str,
        help='directory with list of classes',
        required=True)
  # some more arguments
  args = parser.parse_args()

  main(args)
```

I've written another python script say B, which uses `flask` to run a web-application on localhost.

I'm trying to import the script A in B as:

`from <folder> import A`

How do I give in the arguments that are required in A for running script B?
**I want to run A inside script B by passing parameters via the main flask python script (viz., the script B).**

I want to use all the functionality of A, but I'd rather not change the structure of A or copy-paste the same exact code inside B.

I've been trying something like:

```
@app.route(...)
def upload_file():
    A.main(classpath = 'uploads/')
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I'm taking inspiration from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28441788/9871400) answer, but I guess I'm missing something.

Does anybody have some idea on how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer which I've [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28441788/9871400) helped me to made it work for my code. Quite simply, efficient use of kwargs can help solve it.

```
.
.
def main(**kwargs):
  file_path_audio = kwargs['classpath']
  # use the other arguments
.
.

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(..)
  parser.add_argument(
        '-c',
        '--classpath',
        type=str,
        help='directory with list of classes',
        required=True)
  # some more arguments
  kwargs = parser.parse_args()

  main(**kwargs)
```

And for the flask script, simply use,

```
@app.route(...)
def upload_file():
    A.main(classpath = 'uploads/', ..) # have to add all the arguments with their defaults
```

I haven't found any other way than to state all the default arguments while using the main function.